# Trouble with begin() of my Map realization

Tags: c++, dictionary, casting, iterator, nodes

help me with figuring out please why I have this error:

**error:**

```
<function-style-cast>: The compiler cannot cast from "const mtm::Node<mtm::MtmMap<int,int,std::less<KeyType>>::Pair> *" to "mtm::MtmMap<int,int,std::less<KeyType>>::iterator"
```

Those are different relevant parts of the code:

**Node:**

```
template <typename DataType>
        class Node {
    public:
        DataType data;
        Node<DataType> *head;
        Node<DataType> *next;

    public:
        Node(const DataType& data) :data(data), head(nullptr) {
            next = nullptr; 
        };
```

**Iterator:**

```
class iterator {
        private:
            Node<Pair>* _ptr = nullptr;
        public:
            iterator(Node<Pair>* ptr = nullptr) : _ptr(ptr) { }

            iterator(const iterator& itr) = default;

            ~iterator() = default;

            iterator& operator=(const iterator&) = default;
```

**Private of MtmMap:**

```
private:
        Node<Pair> _pairs;
        iterator _it; 
        int _size;
```

**The code when the error shows:(in body of MtmMap)**

```
iterator begin() const{
            if (this->_size) {
                this->_it = iterator(&_pairs);
            }
            return this->_it;
        }
```

Comment: Are you trying to redefine a member reference with this->_it = iterator( &_pairs);?

Comment: that's typo, but still the same problem after fixing it. The problem is that the error appears despite that I call iterator ctor with Node<Pair> * variable, but it doesn't see it.

Comment: Can't tell what scope things are in, and you haven't shown enough code. Maybe try `this->_it = ::iterator(&_pairs);` (on the assumption your `iterator` is declared globally but is being hidden by the `iterator` within `std::map`, which I'm assuming `MtmMap` is derived from).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've declared `begin` as `const`. Thus this in this line:

```
this->_it = iterator(&_pairs);
```

`&_pairs` has resulting type of `const Node<Pair>*`. Your `iterator` class only accepts a non-const pointer to `Node<Pair>` (implicit conversion from a const-pointer to a non-const-pointer is not allowed).

Either `iterator` needs to be modified to accept (and store) a const-pointer, or `begin` needs to drop the `const` qualifier.

Comment: Yes, you're right, that among many other trouble )) but thanks. i've handled it already.